# Belowskip on minted?

Tags: spacing, minted

Is it possible to remove the spacing below the code of a `minted` environment? When I have a block of code underneath another it doesn't produce any spacing (which is what I want), but it does for text (which I don't want). Is there somthing similar like `belowskip` of the `listings` package that I can use as a global option?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\newminted{python3}{linenos=true} % belowskip=0pt?

\begin{python3code}
print("Hello world")
\end{python3code}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`minted` uses the package `fancyvrb` to create the environment. `fancyvrb` uses a modification of `trivlist`. So you can have to modify the `trivlist`.

One possibility is shown below. Here I created a new key `belowskip`.

**EDIT**

In combination width `\newminted` it also works (see comment below):

```
% pdflatex --shell-escape 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
\newlength\minted@belowskip
\define@key{minted@opt}{belowskip}[\@topsepadd]
{\setlength{\minted@belowskip}{#1}}

\def\minted@endparenv{%
  \addpenalty\@endparpenalty\addvspace\minted@belowskip\@endpetrue}
\def\FV@EndList{%
  \FV@ListProcessLastLine
  \FV@EndListFrame
  \minted@endparenv
  \endgroup
  \@endpetrue}
\makeatother
\newminted{python3}{linenos=true, belowskip=4cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{python3code}
print("Hello world")
\end{python3code}

Some text


\begin{python3code}
print("Hello world")
\end{python3code}

Some text

\end{document}
```

---

**Orig**

```
% pdflatex --shell-escape 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
\newlength\minted@belowskip
\define@key{minted@opt}{belowskip}[\@topsepadd]
{\setlength{\minted@belowskip}{#1}}

\def\minted@endparenv{%
  \addpenalty\@endparpenalty\addvspace\minted@belowskip\@endpetrue}
\def\FV@EndList{%
  \FV@ListProcessLastLine
  \FV@EndListFrame
  \minted@endparenv
  \endgroup
  \@endpetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[belowskip=4cm]{python}
print("Hello world")
\end{minted}

Some text


\begin{minted}[belowskip=0pt]{python}
print("Hello world")
\end{minted}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to break if I use it as an option in my environment:

`\newminted{python3}{linenos=true, belowskip=0pt}

\begin{python3code} ... `

Comment: @pg-robban: It works also with `\newmindet`.

Comment: Must be a conflict with the other packages I'm using: `package calc error 'xkv@tempa@toks' invalid at this point.` But the MWE seems to be working so I'll accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that `calc` is loaded by `minted` itself. I can't from that output what the conflict is. But if you wanted to track it down, you could probably use **just** `calc` with whatever your other packages are to minimize the bug.