# Possible bug in minted package

Tags: minted

(just now while typing the topic title I found [possible related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37119/14757) but my post is too long to discard it now :-) )

(the `minipage`s is only to show side by side. I'll not use it)

I'm using `minted` package to type code blocks.

The basic environment is `minted` which produces the code block with nice vertical spaces above/below the code (see example below: left side).

We can change the style of the code block making use of `\newminted`.

But the problem is that if we use a background color for the block those vertical spaces are affected (see example below: right side).

[image]

Reading the `minted` documentation (section 8.4) we find the code (commented 2nd line in original form)

```
\newenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
\def\minted@bgcol{#1}
\noindent
\begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}}
 {\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\colorbox{\minted@bgcol}{\usebox{\minted@bgbox}}}
```

So I noticed that there is no vertical space around the box and then I edited that code and inserted `\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}` and `\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}` before and after `lrbox`, as shown below.

```
% from texdoc minted
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
\def\minted@bgcol{#1}
\vspace{\abovedisplayskip} %%             my code
\noindent%
\begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}}
 {\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\vspace{\belowdisplayskip} %%             my code
\colorbox{\minted@bgcol}{\usebox{\minted@bgbox}}}
\makeatother
```

The result was almost satisfactory since the space after the code is not the same.

[image]

**Question 1:** is this the better way to correct the problem?

**Question 2:** What is the correct space to be inserted in this case?

**Question 3:** Could it be a bug in the package code?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,paperheight=13cm,paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[red!30!white]
          (current page.south west) grid[step=5mm]
          (current page.north east);
        \draw[red!50!white]
          (current page.south west) grid[step=10mm]
          (current page.north east);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }


\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted{tex}{%
    bgcolor=bg,%
%    gobble=0,%
%    linenos=true,%
%    firstline=1,%
%    firstnumber=1,%
%    fontfamily=courier,%
%    fontsize=\footnotesize,%
%    numberblanklines=false,%
%    numbersep=3mm,%
%    xleftmargin=6mm,%
%    xrightmargin=5mm%
}

% from texdoc minted
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
\def\minted@bgcol{#1}
\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
\noindent%
\begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}}
 {\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
\colorbox{\minted@bgcol}{\usebox{\minted@bgbox}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
\lipsum[2]%
\begin{minted}{tex}
  \begin{equation}
   \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
  \end{equation}
\end{minted}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
\lipsum[2]%
\begin{texcode}
  \begin{equation}
   \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
  \end{equation}
\end{texcode}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you really want good, configurable background colors (and perhaps want code that will break across pages when there is a background color), you should use a proper framing package like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` instead.  The current background color in `minted` could probably be improved, but given its limitations (only a few lines of code), framing packages are a better solution in many cases.

Comment: Perhaps related: [How to keep a constant baseline skip when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764)

Comment: @Werner, sorry. I don't know if this is the case but the `minipage` was used only to show side by side. I guess that my problem is not related with the `minipage`.