# Aboveskip on minted?

Tags: spacing, minted

I'm using minted inside a multicol enviroment and would like to remove the spacing at the start of the first column.
I found the answer for `belowskip` and I am looking for the same code for `aboveskip`:

[Belowskip on minted?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37117/belowskip-on-minted)

**Edit:**
[muzimuzhi-z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/79060/muzimuzhi-z)  provided a great answer.
This allows for nice two column listings:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
% new fancyvrb options "above space" and "below vspace"
\define@key{FV}{above vspace}[\topsep]{\def\FancyVerbAboveVspace{#1}}
\define@key{FV}{below vspace}[\topsep]{\def\FancyVerbBelowVspace{#1}}

% redefine existing option "vspace"
\define@key{FV}{vspace}[\topsep]{%
  \def\FancyVerbAboveVspace{#1}\def\FancyVerbBelowVspace{#1}}

% init
\fvset{vspace}

% patch fancyvrb internals
\xpatchcmd\FV@ListVSpace
  {\@topsepadd=\FancyVerbVspace}
  {\@topsepadd=\FancyVerbAboveVspace}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd\FV@EndList
  {\@endparenv}
  {\@topsepadd\dimexpr\@topsepadd-\FancyVerbAboveVspace
                                 +\FancyVerbBelowVspace\relax
   \@endparenv}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\minted@def@optfv{vspace}
\minted@def@optfv{above vspace}
\minted@def@optfv{below vspace}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicolrule}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Codebox}

  \definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{.1, .1, .1}
  \setbeamercolor{blackcodebox}{fg=white,bg=codebg}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true]{blackcodebox}
    \small Comet ML\vspace{4pt}
    \hrule
    \setlength\multicolsep{1pt} % no multicol top margin
    \SetMCRule{line-style=solid-circles,color=white,width=2pt}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      foo
      \usemintedstyle{monokai}
      \inputminted[tabsize=2,breaklines,fontsize=\scriptsize,python3=true,%
        below vspace=0pt,above vspace=0pt]{python}{example.py}
      bar
    \end{multicols}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image: Beamer codebox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fancyvrb` has an undocumented option `vspace` which controls both the above and below skip. This option has default and initial value `\topsep` and was supported since [`fancyvrb` v3.0 2018/11/01](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty?r1=49044&r2=49045&pathrev=61154&)

In below example two more options `above vspace` and `below vspace` are added. Now

- total above skip is `<above vspace> + \parskip (+ \partopsep)`
- total below skip is `<below vspace> + \parskip (+ \partopsep)`

see https://latexref.xyz/list.html for how the above and below skip is calculated in a normal list.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% new fancyvrb options "above space" and "below vspace"
\define@key{FV}{above vspace}[\topsep]{\def\FancyVerbAboveVspace{#1}}
\define@key{FV}{below vspace}[\topsep]{\def\FancyVerbBelowVspace{#1}}

% redefine existing option "vspace"
\define@key{FV}{vspace}[\topsep]{%
  \def\FancyVerbAboveVspace{#1}\def\FancyVerbBelowVspace{#1}}

% init
\fvset{vspace}

% patch fancyvrb internals
\xpatchcmd\FV@ListVSpace
  {\@topsepadd=\FancyVerbVspace}
  {\@topsepadd=\FancyVerbAboveVspace}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd\FV@EndList
  {\@endparenv}
  {\@topsepadd\dimexpr\@topsepadd-\FancyVerbAboveVspace
                                 +\FancyVerbBelowVspace\relax
   \@endparenv}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\newcommand\controlGroup[1]{\par
  \subsection*{#1}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1][1]
    \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
    content \% trivlist env\\
    content \% control group
    \end{flushleft}
    \lipsum[1][1]
  \end{minipage}
  \qquad\ignorespaces
}

\controlGroup{Default}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1][1]
  \begin{Verbatim}
content % by default, above skip =
content % below skip = \topsep
  \end{Verbatim}
  \lipsum[1][1]
\end{minipage}

\controlGroup{\texttt{vspace=0pt}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1][1]
  \begin{Verbatim}[vspace=0pt]
content
content
  \end{Verbatim}
  \lipsum[1][1]
\end{minipage}

\controlGroup{\texttt{above vspace=0pt}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1][1]
  \begin{Verbatim}[above vspace=0pt]
content
content
  \end{Verbatim}
  \lipsum[1][1]
\end{minipage}

\controlGroup{\texttt{below vspace=0pt}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1][1]
  \begin{Verbatim}[below vspace=0pt]
content
content
  \end{Verbatim}
  \lipsum[1][1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following three lines add `minted` interface:

```tex
\minted@def@optfv{vspace}
\minted@def@optfv{above vspace}
\minted@def@optfv{below vspace}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!